# How to make the browser redirect me to HTTPS on a specific site?

Tags: tls, web-browser

I recently learned that StackExchange sites have both HTTP and HTTPS versions, so, for instance, both http://security.stackexchange.com/ and https://security.stackexchange.com/ are accessible.

By default, Google redirects users to the HTTP version, and there is no automatic redirection to HTTPS on the site. While I'm relatively OK with that when working from home, it annoys me a lot when accessing those sites from a hotel or, in general, any WiFi hotspot.

Is there a way to force browsers (in my case, the latest stable versions of Chrome and Chromium on Ubuntu and Chrome on Android Lollipop) to go to HTTPS version, even when following the http:// link from Google?

Comment: Do you want this for just a few sites, or do you want it for everything?

Comment: @Anders: originally, I need it for StackExchange sites only, but if there is a way to do it for every website which supports HTTPS, it's even better.

Comment: I'm surprised that StackExchange doesn't automatically redirect you to "https" if you're on "http".

Comment: @SecureServer: there are many questions about that in Meta. The [official response](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270642/240613) is that the HTTPS support by StackExchange sites is still incomplete, therefore they keep HTTP as the default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can install plugins to your browser such as HTTPS everywhere:

https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere%20

HTTPS Everywhere was inspired by Google's increased use of HTTPS and is designed to make HTTPS automatically used whenever possible.

It automatically switches sites from insecure "HTTP" to secure "HTPS". It will protect you against many forms of surveillance and some forms of censorship.

Comment: Wow! Simple to use and works great. Thank you very much!